# Can we customize/override this "+" icon on the Salesforce Calendar? If Yes, How?

Tags: calendar, public, public-calendar

[image]

I want to auto-populate some fields from an object to event while going through the calendar. Cause the plus icon on calendar redirects to the next page, i wanted to know if we can anyhow override this plus icon. Please help.
thanks.